# How to search an array of associative arrays with multiple required needles and return the indexes?

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, filtering

I am trying to search an array of associative arrays and get the keys of the subarrays that meet all search criteria.

Here is my example:

```
$list = [
['name' => 'this is items name',
'number' =>  1,
'description' => 'this is description',
'id' => 'just some id',],

 ['name' => 'this is items name2',
'number' =>  1,
'description' => 'this is description2',
'id' => 'just some id',],

 ['name' => 'this is items name3',
'number' =>  1,
'description' => 'this is',
'id' => 'just some id',],
];
```

I would like to search for "this description" and get the keys of an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 )
```

I tried this:

```
$array_key = array_keys(array_column($list, 'description'), 'this description', false);
```

but it only finds the key if search words exactly match the value. How can I solve this problem?

More precisely, how can I search the whole array not only the column description?

Comment: Thinking that array_filter with custom search function can help you to solve the problem

Comment: what kind of search are you trying to achieve? some kind of similarity percentage?

Comment: i think you can loop through array and search using `strpos` function. Or you can use `array_search` to search but it will search in all values not only description.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want, but I guess this might be a good starting point:

```
<?php

$list = [
    [
        'name' => 'this is items name',
        'number' =>  1,
        'description' => 'this is description',
        'id' => 'just some id'
    ],

     [
         'name' => 'this is items name2',
        'number' =>  1,
        'description' => 'this is description2',
        'id' => 'just some id'
    ],

    'test' => [
         'name' => 
         'this is items name3',
        'number' =>  1,
        'description' => 'do not find this one',
        'id' => 'just some id'
    ],
    'preserve_this_key_please' => [
         'name' => 
         'this is items name4',
        'number' =>  1,
        'description' => 'this is something, key preserved',
        'id' => 'just some id'
    ],    
];
function getKeysBy($array, $key, $value){
    return array_keys(array_filter($array,function($val) use ($key,$value) {
        //return $val[$key] === $value;//exact match
        return strpos($val[$key], $value) === 0;
    } ));
}
var_dump(getKeysBy($list, 'description', 'this is'));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  string(24) "preserve_this_key_please"
}
```

Working code:

https://3v4l.org/Gs3He

Note: in this example the keys are preserved, i.e. if a key is a string like in the last item. If you don't need it, then the array_column + friends is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this three cases as starting point:

```
$list=[
['name' => 'this is items name',
'number' =>  1,
'description' => 'this is description',
'id' => 'just some id',],

 ['name' => 'this is items name2',
'number' =>  1,
'description' => 'this is description2',
'id' => 'just some id',],

 ['name' => 'this is items name3',
'number' =>  1,
'description' => 'this is',
'id' => 'just some id',],
];

$search='this description';
//first type of search : any of the word containing in the needle sentence
$regex='#'.implode('|',preg_split('#\s#',$search)).'#';
$array_key = array_keys(preg_grep($regex,array_column($list, 'description')));
print_r($array_key);

//second type of search : all of the words containing in the needle sentence
$array_key=[];
$needles=preg_split('#\s#',$search);
$count_needles=count($needles);
$regex='#'.implode('|',$needles).'#';
foreach(array_column($list,'description') as $k=>$v){
    if(preg_replace($regex,'###',$v,-1,$count)){
        if($count===$count_needles) $array_key[]=$k;
    }
}

print_r($array_key);

//third type of search : based on similarity percentage 

$thereshold=50.0;
$array_key=[];
$needles=preg_split('#\s#',$search);
$count_needles=count($needles);
$regex='#'.implode('|',$needles).'#';
foreach(array_column($list,'description') as $k=>$v){
    if(preg_replace($regex,'###',$v,-1,$count)){
        if(min($count,$count_needles)/max($count,$count_needles)*100>$thereshold) $array_key[]=$k;
    }
}

print_r($array_key);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a `foreach` and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a regex to match from `this` until the first occurence of `description` by matching any character one or more times non greedy `.*?`:

[`\bthis.*?description`](https://regex101.com/r/SNVhje/1)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/\bthis.+?description/', $value["description"])) {
        $result[$key] = $key;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1q163)

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpretting your question as: How to search a multidimensional array by searching for multiple needle strings -- all of which are required -- among all of the values in a given subarray and return the index of each qualifying subarray.

My solution seeks direct results by condensing the subarray data into a single string to be checked in an iterative fashion.  As soon as a subarray is deemed "disqualified", the loop is directed to process the next subarray for highest efficiency.

*note, if you specifically need to make "whole word" matching then regex with word boundaries will be necessary.

If you are not familiar with what `continue` does, here is a [link to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N288o))

```
$qualifiers = [];
$needles = explode(" ", "this description");

foreach ($list as $index => $set) {
    $smashed = implode($set);
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        // echo "\n$smashed";
        if (strpos($smashed, $needle) === false) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $qualifiers[] = $index;
}
var_export($qualifiers);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 1,
)
```

p.s. if you are processing a resultset from a database query, it would be better / more direct to perform your filtering task within the query because then you would avoid generating a resultset which is bloated with data that you don't want.